# Is it possible to dereference an object to another object inside his own method?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, copy, dereference

I have a question about some C++ problem. Let's say I have a really big class called `BigClass` and I say `BigClass* foo = new BigClass();`

Let's say I have a method inside BigClass that defines another local object `tmp` of type BigClass and at the end of the method, I check if there was the error by doing some stuff with `tmp` and if not I want to dereference `this` to that object. I don't want to copy all the arguments from `tmp` to `this`, because the object is too big and the process would be slow. Is there any way to dereference the object inside its own method?

Example:

```
class BigClass
{
    int a;
    long b;
    std::vector<int> c;
    // other members...

    void replace()
    {
        BigClass* tmp = new BigClass();
        // do some calculations with tmp
        *this = tmp; // problem
    }
}
```

**Why is *this = tmp a problem?**

I defined an operator= that just does something like this:

```
this.a = src.a;
this.b = src.b;
this.c = src.c;
.
.
.
```

But there I make a copy of all member variables and that is slow. I want to simply dereference the object instead of copying all member variables.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: If you don't want to copy, `move` it. Though something like `this = new Bigclass()` is illegal.

Comment: "Is there any way to dereference the object inside its own method?" not quite clear, are you asking if you can do `*this` ? yes you can. Some code would really help

Comment: Dereferencing a pointer does not copy its value. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: It sounds like you want to reassign the `this` pointer. Consider if your `BigClass` lives on the stack.

Comment: An instance of a class does not automatically know who has a copy of its `this` pointer, so there's no generic way to have `this` replaced with that of `temp` without copying individual fields, as far as I know.

Comment: If you add an example of what you're trying to do, I'll vote for reopen

Comment: if you want to copy only some, but not all members from `tmp` to `this` then of course you can do that. If your assignment operator is already copying all then you can consider to write a private `copy_partial` that copies only the desired members

Comment: you would probably do: delelete this; return tmp; If so, that's a valid operation in C++

Comment: _I don't want to copy all the arguments from `tmp` to `this`_ — I assume you mean to copy all the member variables/subobjects. Then, why? What is your reason for not-to-copy? If for performance reasons, you can simply move them, by `*this = std::move(tmp);`.

Comment: `*this = tmp // problem` — Which problem?

Comment: @DanielLangr: I think OP is trying to say they want something like `this = new BigClass()`

Comment: Your `operator=` is slow because it copies member variables. Define and use a _move-assignment_ `operator=` (defaulted may do). It will likely be much faster, if you have subobjects such as vectors. Another option is, e.g., something like _PIMPL idiom_. When you work with an extra level of indirection, then, move-assignment is basically just an assignment of a single pointer (plus destructor of the inner object). However, this adds an additional overhead elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to copy, you can move it instead:

```
struct BigClass {
    void func() {
        BigClass tmp;

        *this = std::move(tmp);
    }
};
```

A move operation usually don't involve dynamic allocation or the copying of large buffers.

If you follow the [rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), the move assignment operator will be defined for you.

Otherwise, you can always define it using a defaulted operator:

```
struct BigClass {
    BigClass& operator=(BigClass&&) = default;

    // ...
};
```

You could also write your own operator, but the defaulted one usually does the job very well.

```
struct BigClass {
    //          quite important ----v------v
    BigClass& operator=(BigClass&& rhs) noexcept {
        this->a = std::move(rhs.a);
        this->b = std::move(rhs.b);
        this->c = std::move(rhs.c);
    }

    // ...
};
```

A move operation is usually very fast, and much faster than `new`.

---

Alternatively, you can also newing an object and assign the pointer to it:

```
struct BigClass {
    auto replace() -> BigClass* {
        auto tmp = new BigClass{};

        // ...

        return tmp;
    }
};
```

Beware as it is much slower since it involve dynamic allocations.

Comment: Thank you very much
This is a really helpful answer :)

Comment: @Delprof I would avoid shared pointers unless necessary. The best would be unique pointers.

Comment: My problem is that I'm using C++10 and move() can not be compiled :D 
So I searched for some solution with shared pointers

Comment: @Delprof surely you can cast to rvalue references. `std::move` is only a cast to rvalue and nothing else. Writing a `move` implementation is not so challenging.